# What is with the unsightly overlap at the top of the index pages in source2e.pdf?

Tags: documentation, latex-base

I notice that in `source2e.pdf`, the Index section has a running header that intersects with the top of the main text on each page, like so:

[image]

(Actually, this seems to happen with some other sections, too, for example "Change History".)

This occurs both in the current version at http://www.tug.org/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf (permalink http://www.webcitation.org/5viCxJBr7) and in the ones included with MiKTeX 2.8 and 2.9.

What causes this -- is it something to do with the fact that these PDFs are using the A4 paper size rather than letter?

(And of course it would also be nice if somebody fixed it at some point...)

Comment: What PDF software are you viewing it in? (But yeah, I see the problem too, in both evince and mupdf, though the version that came with my TeXlive install is fine.)

Comment: The version on CTAN seems to have wrong margins in the appendix. I wonder why.

Comment: Well, I've tried both AcroRd32 and gsview32 (Ghostscript 9.00).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem has been corrected in an update after the release of the tex live 2010 dvd.
the updated version can be found in the current tex live repository, at
http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf

it's best to use the `tlmgr` facility to update your local copy.

Comment: Mmm, so I'm supposed to use `tlmgr` to update my copy of **MiKTeX**? Somehow, I'm a bit skeptical about the utility of attempting this :-). (And shouldn't the one on CTAN also be fixed?)

Answer (score 0):

I can not see it. I run the document source for a4paper and for letter with `pdflatex` and always get the correct headings:

[image]

Comment: But do you see it if you follow SamB's links?

Comment: @Hendrik: sure, I wanted to say that I cannot see it when running it from the source.

Comment: Then it would indeed be interesting how they managed to get the wrong output.